# Was the doctor's response influenced by Angela?

Tags: the-office

I just finished watching The Office and one thing that bugs me is that Dwight turns out to be the father of Phillip in the last season, even though a DNA test showed he was not the father. Has Angela influenced the news that the doctor gave them? And if not, how come Angela knows that Dwight is indeed the father, as she says in the last season?

Comment: I could very well be misremembering but didn't Angela have fake DNA tests that claimed Dwight wasn't the father. I remember there was the part when Dwight steals a diaper and tries to get that DNA tested but I think it is later revealed that it was the Halpert's baby's diaper? And I think at the end Angela reveals that Dwight was actually the father all along and confirms that the initial DNA tests she had that showed Dwight wasn't the father were fake.

Comment: It being the Halpert's baby's diaper would explain why the DNA test can back negative. However, I don't remember their being a test performed by Angela separately.

Comment: yeah I'm likely misremembering, it has been a while since I've seen the series. I also don't remember if they do hint at it being Halpert's baby's diaper or if that is confirmed in the series. I might've just read a theory that claimed that was the case.